# How to push object to array list?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Once method `addValue` invoked i want to add selectedUsers object value to array list , New to AngularJs is there any better way to implement this using AngularJs ?.

main.html

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in userList track by $index">
          <td st-ratio="20">{{user.attuid}}</td>
          <td st-ratio="30">{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}</td>
          <td st-ratio="15" ng-bind-html="user.type"></td>
          <td st-ratio="15">{{user.email}}</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.selected" ng-click="addValue(user)"> </td>
          <!--<td st-ratio="20" class="text-right">
            <button type="button" ng-click="editUser($index, user)" class="btn btn-primary">
              Approve
            </button>
          </td>-->
        </tr>
```

ctrl.js

```
var selectedUsers = {
    attuid: '',
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: ''
};

$scope.addValue = function(user) {
    $scope.selectedUsers = $scope.selectedUsers || [];
    $scope.selectedUsers.push({
        attuid: $scope.user.attuid,
        firstName: $scope.user.firstName,
        lastName: $scope.user.lastName,
        email: $scope.user.email
    });


};
```

Comment: This looks fine.. IMO

Comment: Without seeing your markup it's hard to tell what exactly you're doing. Your `addValue()` function passes "user" but it is never used

Comment: push is the fastest method to insert in the array in javascript and you already have it in your code. What's the issue

Comment: added html to question, I want to save each user information to `$scope.selectedUsers` when checkbox clicked

Comment: If you're after a code review there is a better community for that than SO which is [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not referencing the right variable:
This is your code:

```
$scope.addValue = function(user) {
    $scope.selectedUsers = $scope.selectedUsers || [];
    $scope.selectedUsers.push({
        attuid: $scope.user.attuid,
        firstName: $scope.user.firstName,
        lastName: $scope.user.lastName,
        email: $scope.user.email
    });


};
```

You are not using the user variable:

```
$scope.selectedUsers = $scope.selectedUsers || [];
$scope.addValue = function(user) {
    $scope.selectedUsers.push({
        attuid: user.attuid,
        firstName: user.firstName,
        lastName: user.lastName,
        email: user.email
    });


};
```

Apart from this, I see you are using a checkbox. So I am guessing you want to push the user only if the checkbox is checked. To do that you will have to check if the user is already in the array and if it is remove it when the checkbox is not selected. This code will be incomplete